# Thingsboard: change of database

Tags: linux, postgresql, cassandra, thingsboard

I have installed thingsboard on Linux. initially it was using Cassandra database, but now i have changed it to postgresql. But the issue is that both the thingsboard and postgresql are not running. The only error in postgresql log file is "Incomplete startup Packet" and thingsboard log file has "all hosts tried query failed(tried: /127.0.0.1:9042)" error.
I have stopped the Cassandra service and also configured the thingsboard.yml file to use postgresql database.
How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more log details, I suggest to fresh install a new ThingsBoard+PostgreSQL instance and migrate the Cassandra db to the new instance using the REST API feature of ThingsBoard, this way you avoid the corruption of PostgreSQL.

The steps are:

1. Install a new instance of ThingsBoard and PostgresSQL
2. Retrieve data via REST API from old instance
3. Send data via MQTT or other supported protocols to new instance

You can find a script which does this automatically in this [repo](https://github.com/AbCthings/thingsboard-data-migration).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but In my experience that you should check up as below.

1. install PostgreSQL on your server.
2. create database like thingsboard inside postgreSQL.
3. configure for using PostgreSQL in thingsboard.yml
4. Run installation script again

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux/#memory-update-for-slow-machines-1gb-of-ram

Comment: I have followed the exact same steps but after running the installation script again i got "Thingsboard installation failed" error